# Unwanted continuous rotation with Quaternion

Tags: transformation, quaternion, glm

I am probably missing something simple but ... this is how I'm calculating the world matrix of my object:

```
glm::translate(glm::mat4(1.f), mPosition) * glm::mat4_cast(mOrientation) * glm::scale(glm::mat4(1.f), mScale);
```

where mOrientation is a glm::quat type and it is set to identity via:

```
mOrientation(glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f))
```

What's strange is that my object keeps rotating over the Y-axis (world space) and to prove that it isn't my loop, I changed my world matrix calculation to:

```
glm::translate(glm::mat4(1.f), mPosition) * glm::rotate(glm::mat4(), 45.0f, glm::vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f)) * glm::scale(glm::mat4(1.f), mScale);
```

And my object is static and is indeed rotated 45 degrees on the Y-axis. The key difference is that with Quaternion, it KEEPS rotating. What am I missing?

Comment: print out/show mOrientation every frame and see if it changes.

Comment: Yup it was something simple :) I thought I was in a different revision ...